# Metaplex create() fails on localhost with: Attempt to load a program that does not exist

Tags: metaplex, nft, metaplex-js

I am following the [Metaplex JS documentation](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#create) to mint an NFT with Metaplex. I have `solana-test-validator` running locally, and my `Connection` object is working fine with `@solana/web3.js` and `@solana/spl-token`. However trying to create an NFT using:

```
  // Start metaplex
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
    .use(keypairIdentity(tokenCreator))
    .use(mockStorage());

  const uploadResponse = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .uploadMetadata({
      name: "First NFT",
    })
    .run();

  console.log(uploadResponse.uri);

  // Create an NFT
  const createOutput = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .create({
      uri: uploadResponse.uri,
      name: "My NFT",
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 500,
    })
    .run();
```

...fails with:

```
MetaplexError: Failed to Send Transaction
    >> Source: RPC
    >> Problem: The transaction could not be sent successfully to the network.
    >> Solution: Check the error below for more information.

    Caused By: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist
```

I understand there's a program that makes NFTs and it doesn't seem to exist on localhost - however when I started `metaplex` I didn't get the option to specify a program address - it looks like metaplex picks the program address for me.

**How can I create an NFT using metaplex/js?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question to help others.

I'm not completely sure (because the Metaplex docs don't tell me, and other programs like SPL work on localhost) but **Metaplex isn't available on localhost by default**.

### Saving the Token Metadata program for use on localhost

Find the address of the Token Metadata Program using https://explorer.solana.com/

[image]

Then in your shell:

```
# Token Metadata program
export METAPLEX_PROGRAM_ADDRESS="metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
solana program dump -u m ${METAPLEX_PROGRAM_ADDRESS} metaplex_token_metadata_program.so
```

Then run:

```
solana program dump -u m ${METAPLEX_PROGRAM_ADDRESS} metaplex_token_metadata_program.so
```

### Using a different network (that likely already has the Token Metadata Program loaded).

Modifying the `Connection` above from:

```
const connection = new Connection("http://127.0.0.1:8899", "confirmed");
```

to:

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
```

### Either method will now create an NFT:

```
{
  response: {
    signature: '4LtQJVaUbEFdj1hxfPtWsauzVmongHqi2ogLFoHNiMaC56EQjBoaAA8sFqxpadKFTRj8XE8DAkwpwvcaajLjPAbX',
    confirmResponse: { context: [Object], value: [Object] }
  },
  mintAddress: PublicKey {
    _bn: <BN: 5050e6a65c08671fa01e90c7ea6bb2deae4e0c6acbb2c4e42075c5cd16586dec>
  },
  metadataAddress: Pda {
    _bn: <BN: 1fe9d690897e239152627074adc0c48dba4ce3d6b7e851bb5d6eccebf90033a9>,
    bump: 251
  },
  masterEditionAddress: Pda {
    _bn: <BN: f9ab790b1919e47e17b325515f57f5d6f6077e641cd4f2e69d648060db2931ae>,
    bump: 255
  },
  tokenAddress: Pda {
    _bn: <BN: 83bb07d2b1fb7041fcca1eedcc285c991eb40b5593dcc3ac948fa949d7b37a5f>,
    bump: 255
  },
  nft: {
    model: 'nft',
    updateAuthorityAddress: PublicKey {
      _bn: <BN: de3762527abedd0a802891770ee0a7306c04dba7c79620de328b03ff7902b90c>
    },
    json: { name: 'First NFT' },
    jsonLoaded: true,
    name: 'My NFT',
    symbol: '',
    uri: 'https://mockstorage.example.com/bV5x6x2y3dvQ5f29MTgV',
    isMutable: true,
    primarySaleHappened: false,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 500,
    editionNonce: 255,
    creators: [ [Object] ],
    tokenStandard: 0,
    collection: null,
    collectionDetails: null,
    uses: null,
    address: PublicKey {
      _bn: <BN: 5050e6a65c08671fa01e90c7ea6bb2deae4e0c6acbb2c4e42075c5cd16586dec>
    },
    metadataAddress: Pda {
      _bn: <BN: 1fe9d690897e239152627074adc0c48dba4ce3d6b7e851bb5d6eccebf90033a9>,
      bump: 251
    },
    mint: {
      model: 'mint',
      address: [PublicKey],
      mintAuthorityAddress: [PublicKey],
      freezeAuthorityAddress: [PublicKey],
      decimals: 0,
      supply: [Object],
      isWrappedSol: false,
      currency: [Object]
    },
    token: {
      model: 'token',
      address: [Pda],
      isAssociatedToken: true,
      mintAddress: [PublicKey],
      ownerAddress: [PublicKey],
      amount: [Object],
      closeAuthorityAddress: null,
      delegateAddress: null,
      delegateAmount: [Object],
      state: 1
    },
    edition: {
      model: 'nftEdition',
      isOriginal: true,
      address: [Pda],
      supply: <BN: 0>,
      maxSupply: <BN: 0>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use localnet, you will need to load any already-existing programs, other than the Solana "native" programs (native programs include the token program, associated token program, compute budget program and others).

There are different ways to load a program to localnet, take a look at the [solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/local-development.html#using-mainnet-accounts-and-programs) and [anchor docs](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/anchor-toml_reference.html) (if you're using anchor).

```
## An example from the cookbook that downloads and loads the Serum Dex program
solana program dump -u m 9xQeWvG816bUx9EPjHmaT23yvVM2ZWbrrpZb9PusVFin serum_dex_v3.so
solana-test-validator --bpf-program 9xQeWvG816bUx9EPjHmaT23yvVM2ZWbrrpZb9PusVFin serum_dex_v3.so --reset
```

Another anchor-specific thing: [the 'anchor-localnet-nfts' app](https://anchor-localnet-nfts.vercel.app/) can generate the `anchor.toml` file that loads NFT both the required programs and mint addresses) in your wallet. E.g. it would look like this:

```
### Generated by anchor-localnet-nfts

## Necessary for test validator
[test.validator]
url = "https://api.devnet.solana.com"
[test]
startup_wait = 20000

## Cloning main programs
# Token program
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
# Associated Token program
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL"
# Token Metadata program
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"

### Cloning NFT-related Accounts from address 5xsj5... on devnet

## NFT #0 (Random NFT)
# Mint address
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "FigzseRcPZ26xE7ZRPUUQvtxuT7sQ1scqCYpRvasABBZ"
# Associated Token Account address
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "BETsRRYAhQRhuSDzRSh4F5kD52JdhsEfYwihduNJzHjB"
# Metadata Program Derived address
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "Dr2iXV9r8vJEu2eCCqsCuAZkzr1sq6uVRBLpncMZA9xz"
```

Comment: Thanks @pepelKO! How would I get the program address for Metaplex? How did you know  "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s" was Metaplex token metadata?

Comment: I've updated my own answer to add instructions for those not using anchor. I'll mark yours as correct though since you helped me!

Comment: Good question, I think it should be possible to find it somewhere in the docs: https://docs.metaplex.com/.
I knew about it, so I just entered "Token" on https://explorer.solana.com and let the autocomplete find it for me.

Comment: @pepelKO How do I know if a program is a native program or a BPF program? For example, `ComputeBudget`? You might be able to help with https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5600/error-downloading-the-computebudget-program-to-use-on-local-validator

Comment: @mikemaccana I'm not sure but I would do the same thing as above: try to find it in the explorer (https://explorer.solana.com/address/ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111) and then check if it has a field where the "Assigned Program Id" or something similar is equal to "Native Loader" or "BPF Loader/BPF Loader 2". If it has, it's a native program.

Comment: @pepelKO I think you're right - if you answer the question above I'll mark you as correct.