# Error downloading the ComputeBudget program to use on local validator

Tags: web3.js, local-cluster, compute-budget

[Per the Solana Cookbook, I'd like to set a transaction priority by using fees](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction).

```
  transaction.add(
    ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
      units: 1_000_000,
    })
  );

  transaction.add(
    ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
      microLamports: 1,
    })
  );
```

This fails on the local validator (but not on `mainnet-beta`) with

> failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid instruction data

which I figure is fair since I haven't added the compute budget program to my local validator like I have with other apps `memo...` for the memo app,  and `meta` for Metaplex etc. However when I run:

```
$ solana program dump -u m ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 compute_budget_program.so
```

I receive:

> Error: ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 is not a BPF program

**How can I use the ComputeBudget program on the local validator?**

Edit: full function, for John:

```
// Taken from
// import { transfer } from "@solana/spl-token";
// And modified to add 'memo'
// And remove redundant options.
export const makeTransaction = async (
  connection: Connection,
  // Original code just calls these 'source' and 'destination' but let's be clearer
  sourceTokenAccount: PublicKey,
  recipientWalletAddress: PublicKey,
  ownerAndPayer: Keypair,
  amount: number | bigint,
  mintAddress: PublicKey,
  memo: string | null = null
): Promise<Transaction> => {
  // These were moved out of the original transfer since they're static

  // SPL Token program account
  const programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID;

  // Signing accounts if `owner` is a multisig
  const multiSigners: Array<Signer> = [];

  log(`TODO: make recipient account for `, mintAddress);

  log(`Sending tokens with memo "${memo}"`);

  const transaction = new TransactionConstructor();

  // 1M microlamports = 1 lamport
  // computeUnitLimit of 1Million units * computeUnitPrice of one microlamport = 1 lamport
  // Transaction now costs 5000 (normal price) + 1 lamport
  // See https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-change-compute-budget-fee-priority-for-a-transaction

  // Normal transaction price is 5000 lamports per signature
  // TODO: remove when
  // https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5600/error-downloading-the-computebudget-program-to-use-on-local-validator
  // is resolved

  const isLocalhost =
    connection.rpcEndpoint.includes("127.0.0.1") ||
    connection.rpcEndpoint.includes("localhost");
  if (!isLocalhost) {
    // "The value provided in microLamports will be multiplied by the CU budget to determine the Prioritization Fee in Lamports."
    log(`Adding priority fee`);

    transaction.add(
      ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
        units: 200_000, // compute units
      })
    );

    transaction.add(
      ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
        microLamports: 5500, // lamports per compute unit
      })
    );
  }

  // Find out if we need to make token account for the recipient and add an instruction for that if necessary

  // Get the reciever token account address (even if it doesn't exist yet)
  let destinationTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    mintAddress,
    recipientWalletAddress
  );

  if (checkTokenAccountCreated(connection, destinationTokenAccount)) {
    log(`Token account already exists, no need to make it`);
  } else {
    log(`Token account does not exist, adding instruction to make it`);
    // If the account does not exist, add the create account instruction to the transaction
    // Logic from node_modules/@solana/spl-token/src/actions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts
    transaction.add(
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        ownerAndPayer.publicKey,
        destinationTokenAccount,
        recipientWalletAddress,
        mintAddress,
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      )
    );
  }

  transaction.add(
    createTransferInstruction(
      sourceTokenAccount,
      destinationTokenAccount,
      ownerAndPayer.publicKey,
      amount,
      multiSigners,
      programId
    )
  );

  // 'memo' is added by us
  // See https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/how-do-i-add-a-note-memo-to-my-solana-transactions-using-web3-js
  // Don't bother adding if memo is an empty string
  if (memo && memo.length) {
    await transaction.add(
      new TransactionInstruction({
        keys: [
          { pubkey: ownerAndPayer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
        ],
        data: Buffer.from(memo, "utf-8"),
        programId: new PublicKey(MEMO_PROGRAM),
      })
    );
  }

  // We need to add these to get an estimated fee
  let blockhashAndHeight = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized");
  transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhashAndHeight.blockhash;
  transaction.feePayer = ownerAndPayer.publicKey;

  return transaction;
};
```

Comment: can you share how are you building and sending the transaction? I just ran the code from the cookbook example with `solana-test-validator` running and it seems to work

Comment: @john it works for me too, in mainnet-beta. Just not on localhost. I've added the relevant parts to the example already (in the spirit of a short reproducible example) but I can do the full paste if you like. One sec...

Comment: To @pepeIKO's point, can you tell us what the output of `solana-test-validator --version` is?

Comment: @stevelusher `solana-test-validator 1.14.16 (src:ab6f3bda; feat:3488713414)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried running an example similar to this one and it works for me. My only idea is that your local validator isn't up to date. You can run `solana validators` to check which version are most validators on and compare it to your local validator's version (`solana -V`).

You can update your local installation with `solana-install update`, or just reinstall completely.